# Camel Apache SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-camel, camel-sql

I am learning to use Apache Camel.

So far I've been trying to create execute a very simple SQL request which seems to not be working. I hope any of you can tell me what is wrong with the code.

Thank you for any potential input.

```
public class CamelMain {

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    Main camelMain = new Main();
    camelMain.configure().addRoutesBuilder(createBasicRoute());
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:9201/dbname");
    dataSource.setUsername("username");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    camelMain.bind("myDataSource",dataSource);
    camelMain.run(args);

}

static RouteBuilder createBasicRoute() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            from("direct:query")
                    .to("sql:insert into FileDetailTable (filename, Status, createdAt) values ('test', 'test', 'test')?dataSource=#myDataSource");
        }
    };
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

can u remove # symbol and try again

```
.to("sql:insert into FileDetailTable (filename, Status, createdAt) values ('test', 'test', 'test')?dataSource=myDataSource");
```

if u get still error can your try this example

main method

https://github.com/erayerdem/camel-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/learncamel/routes/Test.java

postgresql route

https://github.com/erayerdem/camel-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/learncamel/routes/PostgresRoute.java